# How do I make this MIPS program run?

Tags: mips

Ok, so I have this program, but I have no idea how to make it run well.
I have a bidimensional array that is stored as an unidimensional array. I chose to read it column by column instead of line by line. I have to take the maximum number out of every column and add it to a sum and then print the sum. Instead of 14 it prints 0.

.data

```
array: .word 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2, 4, 6, 8
n: .word 3
m: .word 3
s: .word 0
i: .word 0
max: .word 0
nr: .word 0

.text
```

main:

```
  li $a0, 0
  lw $t2, n 
  lw $t3, m
  mul $t1,$t2,$t3 
  lw $t4, max
  lw $t6, s  
  lw $t0, i
  lw $t7, nr

  pas1:
  bge $t0, $t1, end
  lw $t5, array($t0)
  blt $t4, $t5, pas2
  j pas3

  pas2:
  move $t4, $t5
  addi $t7, $t7, 4

  pas3:
  beq $t7, $t2, pas4
  addi $t0, $t0, 4
  j pas1

  pas4:
  add $t6, $t6, $t4 
  li $t4, 0
  li $t7, 0 
  addi $t0, $t0, 4
  j pas1

  end:  
  li $v0, 1
  la $a0, ($t6)
  syscall

  li $v0,10
  syscall
```

Comment: What do you mean by "run well"? What output and behavior are you expecting, and what are you getting instead? What are you trying to do?

Comment: I have a bidimensional array that is stored as an unidimensional array. I chose to read it column by column instead of line by line. I have to take the maximum number out of every column and add it to a sum and then print the sum. Instead of 14 it prints 0.

Comment: You should [edit] your question with this information.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't think it was necessary. I thought I only had some language problem in my code.

Comment: Help? I need it for tomorrow.

Comment: Please see [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)